# FaceTime option unavailable for an iPhone contact

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, facetime

I do not see the FaceTime option for a contact who has an iPhone. I am quite sure it was there and I used it but then it went away. I am still able to use Siri to make a FaceTime Audio call to this user. The Video icon is not active for this user either. They have allowed FaceTime in their Settings and I am not blocked. The phone icon says iPhone underneath it.

I am running iOS 11.4.1 on an iPhone SE. The contact has an iPhone 6s running iOS 12.0. I have restarted my device but to no avail. I have other contacts where the FaceTime option is available.

Both I and this contact (my wife) are new iPhone purchasers and have not set up an Apple ID yet.

What other information can I provide?

Edit for New Information:
I found the following at www.quora.com
Predrag Vasic writes (with respect to missing Face Time Icon in iOS 12)

> If the person you want to call has an iCloud id associated with the
>   number you want to call, there will be video and audio icons for
>   FaceTime next to that number in that person”s contact card.

The person (my wife) does not yet have and iCloud ID so hopefully when she returns & sets it up I will see a FaceTime icon associated with her #.  I can use both Siri and Recent Calls to accomplish the task, I just want to know why the icon is not there.